# Log-in to a website using Google, Facebook or Twitter accounts with Python

Tags: python, facebook, twitter, authentication, google-account

I am making a web application that will monitor the amount of members and discussions in each one of the groups listed here (http://www.codecademy.com/groups#web) and display that information in nice graphs.

However, as you have already seen, it looks like I need to create an account and login with it.

Having in mind that my project is using Python for the server side, how do I do it? Which API is easier? (Google, FB or twitter?)

I would really love if you could also provide some examples because I am really new at this (and at Python too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official wrapper around the Twitter API for Python is [this one.](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) I used it and it's very easy. You should first read [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) and also register an application to get OAuth keys.

Example:

```
import twitter

# Remember to put these values
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="",
                  consumer_secret="",
                  access_token_key="",
                  access_token_secret="")

# Get your timeline
print api.GetHomeTimeline()
```

Hope it helps.